# Becoming a Kafka Consumer with Kerberos

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, rhel7, kafka-topic, keytab

I'm new to `Apache-kafka` and I'm involved in a project where I have to setup a Kafka Consumer in `RHEL7`. The goal is to subscribe into topics in an external server.

I installed `Apache Kafka` and set up a sample producer and a sample consumer, both locally. It works and `Kafka Consumer` is able to receive data from the producer.

However, becoming a consumer for the external server is more complicated as it requires `Kerberos authentication` using a `keytab` file. I'm somewhat lost in where to begin with.

Is there a sample consumer which I could use to connect and check the message stream?
Does `Kerberos authentication` require some installation other than generating the keytab file?
What would be the best approach?

Comment: Who setup the external server? They should be the ones giving your keys and know how to configure the clients

Comment: I'm given credentials and steps to create the keytab file. Other than that, I'm told to setup a consumer 'as usual'.

Comment: Have you seen this Cloudera documentation? https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.1/kafka-securing/topics/kafka-secure-kerberos-enable.html

Comment: I was able to subscribe to topics through a Kafka consumer script. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Feel free to provide your working solution below as an answer